# Does "safer" security setting on Tor disable javascript on HTTP .onion sites?

Tags: security, javascript

In TOR manual we have the following:

> Safer (...) **JavaScript is disabled on all non-HTTPS sites**; some fonts
> and math symbols are disabled; audio and video (HTML5 media) are
> click-to-play.

I was wondering whether this apply to .onion HTTP sites, since most of them are not HTTPS. Logic would dictate that when .onion site is HTTP "safer" security setting would block JavaScript on such site.

Am I right? Or above just applies to clearnet sites?

Thanks

Comment: I think it disables on all sites, because I came across some illegal .onion sites saying that it's better to disable javascript because "you're gonna sent to jail".